# Always return Monday and Sunday of previous complete week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This works:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,'19000108',GETDATE()),'19000101'),
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,'19000108',GETDATE()),'19000107')
```

What is does is what ever date it currently is it will return the previous week't Monday and Sunday.

It is concise but to my mind not very readable - as it relies on 8 Jan 1900 being a Sunday - which isn't something many people remember !

What is a simpler more readable script alternative with the same functionality?

Comment: Is it a must to do this in a SQL statement, or rather can you use java date objects to query with?

Comment: There is more than one way to get the results you want, but none of them are going to be particularly readable.

Comment: I provided an answer below but I think the best solution is to just add a short comment to your existing query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) * -1) - 5, GETDATE()),
    DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) * -1) + 1, GETDATE())
```

Result (when GETDATE() = '2014-05-19 13:00:16.557'):

```
2014-05-12 13:00:16.557    2014-05-18 13:00:16.557
```

With the time removed:

```
SELECT
    CAST(FLOOR(CAST( DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) * -1) - 5, GETDATE()) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME),
    CAST(FLOOR(CAST( DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) * -1) + 1, GETDATE()) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Result:

```
2014-05-12 00:00:00.000     2014-05-18 00:00:00.000
```

A simpler version with the time removed but may not be ideal because of the DATE type:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) * -1) - 5, GETDATE())),
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) * -1) + 1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `WEEKDAY` together with constants since you can't rely on that `WEEKDAY` is static. Use `SELECT @@DATEFIRST` to see your current start-day-of-week (it is 7) and change it with `SET DATEFIRST 1`. Now your script doesn´t work...

Comment: +1 thanks for the time spent on this. Good to have options. Seems like elegance will not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go for the fact that 1900-01-01 is a Monday.

```
select DATEADD(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

And then go from there:

```
select DATEADD(week, -1, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, getdate()), 0))
       ,DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Comment: +1 I think this is a good solution. Use of 0: just done a search and '19000101' is sargable but 0 isn't so could perform better is some contexts + 0 evaluates to '19000101' so for the sake of a few keystokes it is preferable + its more readable.